# "lesser visual fidelity" vs. "lower visual fidelity"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm wondering whether to use "**lower visual fidelity**" or "**lesser visual fidelity**" when comparing two identical scenes in two documentaries, one being remastered and thus of higher quality.

The complete sentence is:

"*The old documentary features the same scenes, alas in lower visual fidelity.*"

Can both of these terms be used? What's the difference?

Comment: In fact, the problem is fidelity. fidelity to what?

Answer (score 2):

Both are probably fine to use. However, according to Google, "lower visual fidelity" is far more commonly used that "lesser visual fidelity". The former search returns over 2000 hits, but the latter returns only 50.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) would be a lot better than using a general Google search. Although it only [gives hits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lesser+fidelity%2C+lower+fidelity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clesser%20fidelity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clower%20fidelity%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clesser%20fidelity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clower%20fidelity%3B%2Cc0) for *lesser fidelity* versus *lower fidelity*, rather than any of the longer terms, it does support the claim given in this answer.

Comment: Also consider *hi-fi* and *lo-fi* - when talking about audio fidelity, it's hard to imagine someone saying *cassettes were of lesser fidelity than vinyl records, but...*. I would definitely go with *lower* (and I think *visual* could be dropped, if the whole thing is about visual fidelity).

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning; the difference is in the metaphor used for visual acuity.

***Lessened*** visual fidelity is a **Quantity** metaphor (part of a **Container** schema), in which *fidelity* is conceptualized as a fungible substance that can be acccumulated, and increased or decreased in amount.

***Lower*** visual fidelity is a **Vertical** metaphor (a common **One-Dimensional** schema), in which *fidelity* is conceptualized as a fungible quantity whose size can be measured and displayed on a vertical (Y-axis) scale, in which higher levels indicate greater quantities of *fidelity*.

*Lessened* is less metaphoric, in that it doesn't introduce the irrelevant vertical dimension  for recording scales that *lowered* does, but only a little bit -- *`UP` is `MORE`*, a part of the [`UP/DOWN` schema](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), is completely assimilated in our culture.